# Insert data into two columns of a table in Laravel Controller using sql

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel-5.5

I have been trying to insert data using query into two columns of a table but there's something missing that its not sending data in the other column named booking_code.
It is inserting the booking_id into the table but not booking_code.

Here is the controller:

```html
public function store(CreatePaymentRequest $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        $booking_id = $request->booking_id;
        $booking_code = Booking::find($booking_id)->booking_code;
        $this['booking_code'] = $booking_code;

        $payment = $this->paymentRepository->create($input);

        Flash::success('Payment saved successfully.');

        return redirect(route('admin.payments.index'));
    }
```

Comment: Could you show what your repository looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [Relevant Documentation Pages](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment)

> You may also use the create method to save a new model in a single line. The inserted model instance will be returned to you from the method. However, before doing so, you will need to specify either a fillable or guarded attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default.

That means that you have to set, in Model, which fields you will allow to be "mass-assigned".

In your case, it will looks something like

```
class Booking extends Model 
(...)
{
   protected $fillable = ['booking_code', (...)];
}
(...)
```

In the code you provided though, I can't see how you build an `$input` variable so maybe the issue is there? Maybe it's just some typo.

Comment: Model is already there
`public $fillable = [
        'booking_id',
        'booking_code',
        'payment',
        'payment_date'
    ];`

Comment: I also tried `$input['booking_code'] = $booking_code;` too